# Alphabet cypher in Rust

Tags: beginner, rust, caesar-cipher

This is my attempt at an [alphabet cypher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Alphabet_Cipher) in Rust. I'm unsure if iteration and pushing to a mutable is the best way to handle building the output; it seems like a good candidate for a map but I can't figure out how to do it. Can anyone help?

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let keyword = env::args().nth(1).unwrap();
    let body = env::args().nth(2).unwrap();
    let transpose_table = get_transpose_table(keyword);

    let mut output = String::new();
    for (input_idx, input_char) in body.char_indices() {
        let transpose_distance = transpose_table[input_idx % transpose_table.len()];
        let transposed_char_idx = char_to_alpha_idx(input_char) + transpose_distance;
        output.push(alpha_idx_to_char(transposed_char_idx % 26));
    }

    println!("{}", output);
}

fn get_transpose_table(keyword: String) -> Vec<usize> {
    return keyword.chars()
                  .map(|character| char_to_alpha_idx(character))
                  .collect();
}

fn char_to_alpha_idx(character: char) -> usize {
    return "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".find(character)
                                       .expect("Bad char for char_to_alpha_idx");
}

fn alpha_idx_to_char(loc: usize) -> char {
    return "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".chars()
                                       .nth(loc)
                                       .expect("Bad loc for alpha_idx_to_char");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sup>**Disclaimer:** I'm a Rust beginner with a background in C and C++. Now that I've lost my credibility, let's have a look at your code.</sup>

## Use rustfmt, clippy and rustc

There are (at least) three helpful tools when one writes Rust code: [`rustfmt`](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt), [`clippy`](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rust-clippy) and the compiler rustc itself.

### Rustfmt provides a common ground

The compiler doesn't yield any warnings, but rustfmt **will** change your code.
As many Rust developers use `rustfmt` (or `cargo fmt`, which calls the former), you should also make a habit of using it. That way others will feel right at home if they look at your code, and the same will hold for you when you look at theirs.

### Clippy's warnings

`clippy` on the other hand will catch common mistakes. In this case its mostly the redundant `returns` in your `idx` functions:

```
fn get_transpose_table(keyword: String) -> Vec<usize> {
    keyword
        .chars()
        .map(|character| char_to_alpha_idx(character))
        .collect()
}

fn char_to_alpha_idx(character: char) -> usize {
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        .find(character)
        .expect("Bad char for char_to_alpha_idx")
}

fn alpha_idx_to_char(loc: usize) -> char {
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        .chars()
        .nth(loc)
        .expect("Bad loc for alpha_idx_to_char")
}
```

There is no need to `return` here. Next, you never consume the `String` in `get_transpose_table`, so we could borrow it instead with `&String`. But in the end, we never use any `String`-specific functionality, therefore we can just use `&str`.

While we're at it, `map(|x| func(x))` is just `map(func)`, so let's change that as-well:

```
fn get_transpose_table(keyword: &str) -> Vec<usize> {
    keyword.chars().map(char_to_alpha_idx).collect()
}
```

All those small improvements were reported by `clippy`.

## Use `T::with_capacity` if you know how many elements you will have

For your main algorithm, you should use `String::with_capacity` if you know the number of characters you want to store:

```
let mut output = String::with_capacity(input.len());
```

Nothing else in your code changes.

## Closures and readability

Apart from better names (`message` instead of `body`, `body_index` or `message_ index` instead of `input_index`) that's all we can do with this algorithm. We *could* transform it into a closure:

```
let output: String = message
    .char_indices()
    .map(|(index, message_char)| {
        let transpose_distance = transpose_table[index % transpose_table.len()];
        let transposed_char_idx = char_to_alpha_idx(message_char) + transpose_distance;
        alpha_idx_to_char(transposed_char_idx % 26)
    })
    .collect();
```

but we only removed mutability. So let's get back to the drawing table. Why do we need `index`? Because we want to know which `usize` we should use from the `transpose_table`. We would like to traverse a **cycle** of those values at the same time as our original message.

That's exactly what [`cycle()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cycle) and [`zip()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.zip) are for:

```
let output: String = transpose_table
    .iter()
    .cycle()
    .zip(message.chars())
    .map(|(transpose_distance, message_char)| {
        let transposed_char_idx = char_to_alpha_idx(message_char) + transpose_distance;
        alpha_idx_to_char(transposed_char_idx % 26)
    })
    .collect();
```

Whether that's easier to understand than your original variant is left to you. However, we can also get rid of the intermediate `Vec`:

```
let output: String = keyword
    .chars()
    .map(char_to_alpha_idx)
    .cycle()
    .zip(message.chars())
    .map(|(transpose_distance, message_char)| {
        let transposed_char_idx = char_to_alpha_idx(message_char) + transpose_distance;
        alpha_idx_to_char(transposed_char_idx % 26)
    })
    .collect();
```

This is a handful, but it works exactly as your previous variant.

## Encapsulate functionality in functions

Now, my main critique point is that you don't provide **a single** function for your cipher. It's hard to test your functionality at the moment, so we better add one and some documentation:

````
/// Applies [The Alphabet Cipher] given by `keyword` to `message`.
///
/// Both `message` and `keyword` must only contain lowercase alphabetic ASCII
/// characters.
///
/// # Panics
/// Panics if any non-lowercase or non-alphabetic ASCII character is encountered.
///
/// # Examples
/// The character 'a' in the keyword won't change the input:
/// ```
/// assert_eq!(alphabet_cipher("aaaaa", "hello"), "hello");
/// ```
///
/// They keyword gets cycled if its  shorter than the message:
/// ```
/// assert_eq!(alphabet_cipher("a", "hello"), "hello");
/// assert_eq!(alphabet_cipher("b", "hello"), "ifmmp");
/// assert_eq!(alphabet_cipher("ab","hello"), "hflmo");
/// assert_eq!(alphabet_cipher("ba","hello"), "iemlp");
/// ```
///
/// [The Alphabet Cipher]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Alphabet_Cipher
fn alphabet_cipher(keyword: &str, message: &str) -> String {
    keyword
        .chars()
        .map(char_to_alpha_idx)
        .cycle()
        .zip(message.chars())
        .map(|(offset, message_char)| {
            let index = char_to_alpha_idx(message_char) + offset;
            alpha_idx_to_char(index % 26)
        })
        .collect()
}
````

The code snippets in the comments also get tested by `cargo test`, but we can also add some more tests to check that our functions work, for example:

```
#[test]
fn alphabet_cipher_rot_a_to_z() {
    assert_eq!(
        alphabet_cipher("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    );
}
```

There are more tests one can come up with, but those are left as an exercise.

## User friendly interface

You use `unwrap()` quite a lot. However, that leaves a user with unhelpful error messages:

```
$ ./cypher test
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', ...

$ ./cypher test test12345
thread 'main' panicked at 'Bad char for char_to_alpha_idx', ...
```

Those error messages aren't that helpful. They're fine for toy programs, but you should view `unwrap` as "I know that this will be `Ok` or `Some`, and it's fine to panic if it isn't, because I don't know how to continue". However, even in those cases, the *end user* should know how to continue. Keep that in mind when you write larger programs.

Comment: Wow. I'd love to see what you had to share if you *weren't* a beginner... Thanks for this.